# PrimeNG TypeError "this._activeIndex.includes" is not a function

Tags: angular, primeng, angular7

I have a component in which I use an accordion.I want to have multiple tabs enabled and a custom activeIndex.
Here is my code :

```
<p-accordion [activeIndex]="index" [multiple]="true">
  <p-accordionTab header="1st tab">
    1st tab content
  </p-accordionTab>
  <p-accordionTab header="2nd tab">
    2nd tab content
  </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

Here is my component class

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-panel',
  templateUrl: './panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel.component.css']
})
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {

  index:number = 1;
  constructor() { 
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    //this.index = 0;
  }

}
```

The problem appears If I want to include both [activeIndex] and [multiple].Any ideas why this is happening?

I use PrimeNG 7 and angular 7

Comment: Docs says - "Index of the active tab or an array of indexes to change selected tab programmatically.", try array of indices, also note that the error suggests an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't be using both. It's either one or the other.

`multiple`: When enabled, multiple tabs can be activated at the same time.

`activeIndex`: Index of the active tab or an array of indexes to change selected tab programmatically.

Because of the way they work, they will be contradicting each other. One is to have several open, the other one is to have just one open.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion

For example:

Imagine you have a function that says `openDoor()` and one that it's called `closedDoor()` if you use them at the **SAME TIME**  they will contradict to each other.

This is what you need:

```
<p-accordion [multiple]="true" >
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 1" [selected]="true">
        Content 1
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">
        Content 2
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
        Content 3    
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

Comment: But what happens If I want to have multiple tabs and the first one selected by default?

Comment: Also notice that If I bind [multiple] to a boolean variable inside my component class the error goes away

Comment: the activeIndex is not to have one accordion open by default. It's to open it programatically. That's why they put the arrows in the example. You have to use the `[selected]="true"` in the tab you want to have open by default @ManosKounelakis

Comment: Accepted and upvoted.Took me some hours for a simillar project that would throw me a strange error.Now I got it

Comment: you can use both see the answer below from @sabithpocker it is incorrect to state you cannot use both because you can tested and it works. You just need to user number[] for your activeIndex variable not straight number when multiple

Answer (score 4):

Docs says:

> Index of the active tab or **an array of indexes** to change selected tab
>   programmatically.

Here is the [related code](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/accordion/accordion.ts#L184) where it sets activeTabs from `_activeIndex`

```
 updateSelectionState() {
        if (this.tabs && this.tabs.length && this._activeIndex != null) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; i++) {
                let selected = this.multiple ? this._activeIndex.includes(i) : (i === this._activeIndex);
                let changed = selected !== this.tabs[i].selected;

                if (changed) {
                    this.tabs[i].animating = true;
                }

                this.tabs[i].selected = selected;
                this.tabs[i].selectedChange.emit(selected);
            }
        }
    }
```

So, for multiple tabs, you should be using an array of indices, not a number.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-panel',
  templateUrl: './panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel.component.css']
})
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {

  indices: number[] = [1, 2];
  constructor() { 
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    //this.index = 0;
  }

}
```

If you are wondering, `this._activeIndex.includes(i)` this is where your error comes from.

Comment: for me this is the correct answer. It functions perfectly with multiple. If you want to start with all closed just set your indices = [-1]  . The thing is a 0 based index so 0 is the first accordian, 1 is the second.